# regex to search a letter

Tags: objective-c, regex

I use regex in Objective-C, I want to search 'a' letter.
After several tests, I see that if I want to search all 'a' letter, I just need to use simple regex:

> a

But if I want to match the 'a' letter at the begin, I need to use regex:

> \Aa*

but not

> \Aa

What the different? Can you explain. Thank you!!!

EDIT:

My string is

> "ad db bd"

Comment: The regex to search for `a` at the beginning is `^a`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer. The correct regex is "\Aa" but I need to use below string to describe regex:

> \\Aa

It's because the escape character in the string, "\\" describe "\".

Thank all of you

Answer (score 1):

The * (asterisk or star) matches the preceding character 0 or more times, for example, tre* will find tree (2 times) and tread (1 time) and trough (0 times).
 Similarly \a* will find a, aa, aaa, and so on while \a only find single instance of a in the string. more you can learn from here http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm.